# ionic 2 sounds stop background music while loading audio

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, audio

I am working on a ionic 2 app and i need to add custom ringtone in my app for messages so i added `Plugin: cordova-plugin-media`  as well as `Plugin: cordova-plugin-nativeaudio` but it stop any other music player so i tried this js code

`var mySound = new Audio('sounds/entering.mp3'); mySound.play();`

it is working with many media players but is stop google play music and anothers music app.

also  i have tried

`cordova add plugin cordova-allow-background-audio`
but this is also not working for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: i have noticed for first load it is not working but after play again music.. its play continuous on play sound. for native-audio and var mySound = new Audio('sounds/entering.mp3'); mySound.play();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many try .. I fixed my problem with use code like as

```
var mySound = new Audio();
var mySound = new Audio('sounds/entering.mp3'); mySound.play();
```

my issue was background music stop on first load.. so i am using like this load first blank.
now its work propely.